# Getting com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.NoSuchResourceActionException while deploying portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am getting com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.NoSuchResourceActionException while deploying a portlet in liferay 7 tomcat server. What I suppose to do?

Comment: I'd recommend to edit your question with *a lot* more information. I don't get that exception. Check [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a start, and don't forget the *exact* versions of Liferay and other involved software.

Comment: That is just too little  information. Could you include the stack?

Comment: you should check which resource actions are checked (ui, serivces) and which are defined in the resource-actions.xml